# Grails: Run code whenever a new session is created?

Tags: session, grails, bootstrapping

Is it possible in Grails to tie into the session creation process?  I'm hoping to run some code whenever a new session is created so that I can set some default session settings that are stored in a session scoped service in a plugin.

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710031/create-session-variable-in-grails-when-session-is-created

Comment: Yes it is. Can use <your_object>.withNewSession { session -> ... } [@doc](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html)

Comment: Thank you for the link Joshua and for the suggestion ludo ... didn't find that link when first searching for this.  Thanks again.

Comment: @ludo_rj withNewSession is for Hibernate sessions, this question is about HTTP sessions. and it's about one that's auto-created, not manually created

Comment: oups sorry, tks Burt.